# Why am i not able to access the property when i use custom helper inside a loop in handlebar.js

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

Here is a portion of the code:

```
<div id="test">
</div>

<script id="home" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#temp}}
    <p>{{fullName name1 "name2"}}</p>
 {{/temp}}
</script>
Handlebars.registerHelper('fullName', function(name1, name2) {
    return name1 + " --- " + name2;
});


var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $('#test'),

render: function() {        
    var temp = Handlebars.compile($('#home').html());
    this.$el.html(temp({name1: 'stack', name2: 'overflow',temp:[1,2,3]}));       
}
});

// **listView instance**: Instantiate main app view.
var listView = new ListView();
listView.render();
```

Look at this jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/charles531/8B97H/
In handlebar.js,

Why am i not able to access name1 and name2 inside the helper function.Why do i get undefined?
If i don't use the loop i am able to access it.

Comment: actually the answer is that inside the loop you have to use ../ to access the parent path property

Comment: What is the temp array for? If you want to print out a list, I would expect that you loop through a collection of models, each model being an entity, having a first and last name. In case you would link events to the items (hover / checkboxes or else), consider using a list item view (tagname li) that you append to a listview (tagname ul).